# How to generate a status time duration matrix from Status event log?

Tags: algorithms, event-sourcing

I am trying to create a duration matrix, that is, time spent in each status based on the status transition event logs.

I have the following event log where status transition time along with old and new status is being captured.

```
| Event Time  | Old Status |  | New Status |
| 2022-10-21T21:22:34.419+0530 | NONE | -----> | To Do |
| 2022-10-30T22:24:48.006+0530 | To Do | -----> | In Progress |
| 2022-10-31T12:56:27.338+0530 | In Progress | -----> | To Do |
| 2022-11-23T13:37:03.142+0530 | To Do | -----> | In Progress |
| 2022-11-23T13:37:14.050+0530 | In Progress | -----> | Done |
```

I am looking to generate a duration matrix through which I can identify time spent in a particular status

```
| Status | Time Spent |
| To Do | 2334 minutes |
```

The trouble is, I am not able to think beyond the brute force approach of looking at event times that are less than the current index and computing the delta, along with identifying the status to which the delta should be attributed. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to keep the current status and its timestamp started in memory, then you can handle each status change event by adding the duration between last status time and this status time to the `Time Spent` column for the last status, and update current status and status time from the event.

You don't even need the `Old Status` in the events as it is redundant except for the first event, where it isn't informative enough as there is no timestamp associated with the old status, so you know in which status you were but not for how long. You may still opt to keep it for consistency checks, but unless you know what to do with an event whose `Old Status` is different from the current status, you are limited to logging the fact and accepting that there may have been a missed event in between and that your accumulated times may therefore be wrong.

If your event listener isn't keeping memory between events, you need to persist the current status somehow, which should not be too difficult (a database or REDIS entry or even a plain old file).